# Null Pointer Exception in render response phase, JSF/Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In server log multiple errors can be found like below

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:95)

What can be the possible reason for this? Though I tried to recreate in I am unable to recreate after several attempt. Any possible reason or any idea related to this issue?

I need to understand why can we get null pointer exception while rendering response in JSF/Primeface?

primefaces v.3.4.1
javax.faces v.2.1.18

if I check the source code of JSF issue is at this line of source code

> ViewDeclarationLanguage vdl =
>                     vh.getViewDeclarationLanguage(facesContext,
>                                                       facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId());

javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD is set to server.

Comment: Hi, I did not get any help from other question, not relevant. Yes it is prehistoric as it was never upgraded and can not be upgraded now. I am searching for any cause which can trigger this. If possible please provide some similar issue link here. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249134/nullpointer-renderresponse-execute-jsf2-1-7 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249134/nullpointer-renderresponse-execute-jsf2-1-7

Answer (score 0):

Check you `xhtml` file for any not closed tags or other xml/html issues. For example `div`s. Id your IDE doesn't do that, then change IDE or use online XML validators.

Comment: Do you actually get this error when you create invalid xhtml?

Comment: In mojarra 2.1.18 or a different version?

Comment: Yes, Exact case was unclosed `<div class="box box-primary">` used in `composition`. The NPE was cased by null returned by facesContext.getViewRoot()

Comment: Version 2.3.4 and primefaces 7

Comment: If you want to reproduce this. You can use adminfaces example project and remove the closing tag for this div - https://github.com/adminfaces/admin-starter-springboot/blob/master/src/main/webapp/car-list.xhtml#L24

Comment: And with a plain jsf application without PrimeFaces? Same problem?

Comment: I've made a test using a page with `html`, `head` and `body`, no beans. And just one not closed `div` inside body. The same problem. However the PrimeFaces was on the classpath, so it might have an influence.

Comment: Can you try without PrimeFaces?